# Website is hosted, I can access it, but my friend cannot reach it?

Tags: node.js, web, google-cloud-platform, hosting

I can visit my website run on node.js with my custom domain. However, when my friend tried to do so, he was meet with a "website coming soon" page. The website loads on my laptop, but not his?

I've tried checking if I'm supposed to publish the website or something, but can't find anything. Tried to search for similar problems others had but can't find any of those either.

The website should load for my friend as it did with me.

Comment: This is an incomplete question and the general topic is likely off topic for stack overflow too.  There is no specific info at all about the technology behind this question, the code, the configuration or ANYTHING that gives us any idea how to help you.  Plus, it sounds like it's probably more of a network configuration or service configuration question than it is a programming question which makes it off-topic for stack overflow.

Comment: Sorry. I'll try improving question asking, altough, the problem seemed to fix itself in this case.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem fixed itself. I waited a day, and then asked my friend to visit the site again. This time it actually loaded the correct folders and files. So now it works like intended.